# HTML5 mediaelementjs volume slider horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mediaelement.js

I am using HTML5 mediaelementjs. It has volume slider going vertical. Is there anyway to set it to horizontal?

There seems to be issue created with this:

https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/197

Is the issue resolved or still pending? Anybody had any luck setting volume slider in horizontal manner?

Comment: The ticket says it's still open.

Comment: alright. Have to wait for next release.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting Question Jaggu; This is some code that might be helpful:

```
 $.extend(mejs.MepDefaults, {
    muteText: 'Mute Toggle',
    hideVolumeOnTouchDevices: true,

    audioVolume: 'horizontal',
    videoVolume: 'vertical'
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!